# dart HTML TableCellElement - cannot get or set colspan

Tags: html, dynamic, dart, cell, html-table

I am creating a HTML table inside the dart code. then i add rows to the table (TableRowElement) and cells (TableCellElement) to the rows. Then I want to set the colspan of the cells. Or even print the colspan.

Here the program crashes (debugger says that the element has no get$colspan). However the API reference (http://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_html/TableCellElement.html#colSpan) shows colspan as an int (its not final either).

At the end, I want to create dynamic tables...

Thanks,
imran

p.s.: code looks like this:

```
  var table = new TableElement();
  table.addRow();
  table.rows.last.addCell();
  print(table.rows.last.cells.last.colspan);
  table.rows.last.cells.last.colspan=2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property is `colSpan` (capital S)

Answer (score 1):

Issue https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15256 was created.

What you are seeing are hints, not warnings, out of the analyzer.  (There is a bug to fix the UI to make this more clear).

If you change `var table` to `TableElement table`, then the analyzer will violate clospan as you probably expected.  Since you declared table as a "var" the analyzer doesn't produce a warning.  Since this can lead to bugs like the one you encountered, we are always in the process of adding hints.

Unfortunately, there seems to be a bug where the propagated type of `table.rows.last.cells.last` is not being resolved.  I am looking into this now.